# How to focus tap on a callout and not on the main view? Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, callout

I have this problem:
I'm developing an app with a map, clusters and markers for locations. When a marker or a cluster is clicked, a callout will open:
1) In the marker's callout I have a textview in it, but I can't scroll it because if I tap on it, the map on the background will move.
2) The cluster's callout is a CollectionView with several items in it, but I can't scroll it (direction set horizontally) because if I tap on the collectionView the map will move as well.

So, as title says, how to focus the tap on the callouts when they are showed?

Thank you!

Comment: What code have you written yourself to try and do this? Please don't just ask people to do the work for you. Tell us what you've tried and what didn't work, to demonstrate that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from giving obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using your own CalloutView class ?

If so, you can implement delegates in order to handle tap or actions on the CalloutView.

Here is a quick implementation example :

Let's imagine you have a favorite button in your CalloutView.

```
 protocol MyCalloutViewDelegate: class
    {
        func MyCalloutViewDidTouchFavorite(calloutView: MyCalloutView)
    }

    class MyCalloutView: CalloutView
    {
      ...

    func favoriteButtonDidTouch()
        {
            self.delegate?.MyCalloutViewDidTouchFavorite(self)
        }
    }
```

And in your MapViewController, you can implement it this way :

```
// MARK: - MyCalloutViewDelegate

    func MyCalloutViewDidTouchFavorite(calloutView: MyCalloutView)
    {
        let viewController: FavoriteViewController = FavoriteViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

    }
```

In this example, when the user will tap on the favorite button in the CalloutView it will navigate to the FavoriteViewController.

I hope this example will help you to handle the tap gesture on your CollectionView in the CalloutView for your specific action.